# validate empty array for an API request

Tags: java, arrays, json, is-empty

My API response contains a blank array: `[]`

how to validate?
For positive scenarios i have jsonarray and jsonobject . here am not sure how to validate the empty array.

```java
public void ValidateEmptyArray() throws JSONException {
    try {
        if(responseJObject.isEmpty()) {
            report.reportPassEvent("Validate cause attribute", "cause value is -"+ responseJObject.getString("cause"));
        } else {
            report.assertFailEvent("Validate cause attribute", "cause value is -"+ responseJObject.getString("cause")+
                    " And expected value is - "+cause);
        }       
    } catch(Exception e) {
            report.assertFailEvent("Validate cause attribute", "cause attribute is not present in the response");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please update the question with code where you are reading the json and converting to java object

Comment: its just a code i gave as an example where i had some response now in response all i get is [] so what shld be done something like 
responseJArray.isempty()?